# Print from array list

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I need to be able to print out all students that have a loan from array list.

Meaning all students with amount above 0.

I already can print all students and how much they own.. but i dont know how to make it print only the students with a loan.

here is the current code

```
public class LoanCompany
{
    private ArrayList<StudentLoan> loans;
    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class LoanCompany
     */
    public LoanCompany()
    {
        loans = new ArrayList<StudentLoan>();
    }
    /**
     * add a loan amount and ID.
     */
    public void addLoan(String ID,int Amount) 
    { 
        StudentLoan newSLoan= new StudentLoan(ID,Amount);
        loans.add(newSLoan); 
    }
    /**
     * Return amount of loans
     */
    public int getNumberOfLoans()
    {
        return loans.size();
    }
    public void printLoanDitails()
    {
        System.out.println("Loan Summery: ");
        int index=0;
        for(StudentLoan loan : loans) {
            System.out.print(index + " : ");
            loan.printDetails();
            index++;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    /**
     * Remove index.
     */
    public void removeLoan(int index)
    {
        if(validIndex(index)) {
            loans.remove(index);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Valid index... validates the index.
     */
   private boolean validIndex(int index)
    {
        boolean valid;        
        if(index < 0) {
            System.out.println("Index must be 0 or a positive number");
            valid = false;
        }
        else if(index >= loans.size()) {
            System.out.println("Index is too large.");
            valid = false;
        }
        else {
            valid = true;
        }
        return valid;
    }
    /**
     * PayOff method, pays off the student loan.
     */
    public void payOff(int index, int Amount)
    {
        if(validIndex(index)) {
            StudentLoan student = loans.get(index);
            student.payOff(Amount);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Index.");
            }
     }
     /**
     * Prints outstanding loans.
     */
    public void printOutstandingLoans()
    {
        System.out.println("Loan Summery: ");
        for(StudentLoan loan : loans ) {
            int index=0;
            if (loan.getAmount() > 0) {
            System.out.print(index + " : ");
            loan.printDetails();
            index++;
            }           
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public void removeClearedLoans() {
       for(StudentLoan loan : loans ) {
           int index=0;
        if (loan.getAmount() == 0) {
            loans.remove(loan);
             System.out.print( "Cleared Loans Removed ");
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're already using `if` in the above code, so you should be able to test if the current student in the loop has a loan. Where's the problem? Also, why do you name a list of loans "loan", and a single loan "loans". It should be the reverse: `s` for plural form, no `s` for singular form.

Comment: Yeah, made a little mistake.. i realized it was wrong, but haven't changed it yet... But thanks for pointing it out again :)

Comment: Self-vandalism rolled back. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209436/self-vandalism-what-is-correct-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that `StudentLoan` has a field `public int loanAmount` then you could do this:

```
for(StudentLoan loan : loans) {
        int index=0;
        if (loans.loanAmount > 0) {
            System.out.print(index + " : ");
            loan.printDetails();
            index++;
        }
    }
```

This way only loans with `loanAmount > 0` are being printed.

If the field `loanAmount` would be `private` you could simply implement a getter method for the field and change the condition to:

```
if (loan.getloanAmount() > 0) {
```

**EDIT**

Answering your question from the comments:

To remove all loans that have a `loamAmount` of 0 we simply add another `if` to the for each loop:

```
for(StudentLoan loan : loans) {
        int index=0;

        // print loans with amount > 0

        if (loan.loanAmount > 0) {
            System.out.print(index + " : ");
            loan.printDetails();
            index++;
        }

        // delete loans with amount = 0

        if (loan.loanAmount == 0) {
           loans.remove(loan) // UNSAFE! see edit below
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Using `.remove` while iterating over a collection is unsafe. It should be done with an `iterator` like so:

```
import java.util.Iterator // add to imports

Iterator<StudentLoan> i = loans.iterator();

while (i.hasNext()) {
    StudentLoan loan = i.next();
    if (loan.getAmount() == 0) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked perfectly! :)
Would you happened to also know how to remove all the loans that have 0 in them?

Comment: It says it couldn't find variable loanAmount.. i also edited my code above to correct the s mistake

Comment: @user3053139 Did you use `getloanAmount` or `.loanAmount` in the if condition for the first part?

Comment: @user3053139 hmm then the second part should work the same way. Or is it telling you in both cases that the variable `loanAmount` can't be found?

Comment: if (loan) is fine.. but .loanAmount or .getLoanAmount for both says cannot find

Comment: @user3053139 ok, please post the code for your class `StudentLoan` in your question as well, then I will be able to tell you how to do it exactly.

Comment: @user3053139 I meant the whole class `StudentLoan` not the method you posted now.

Comment: @user3053139 ah well there it is, the method is called `getAmount` instead of `getloanAmount`. Simply change it to that and then you should be fine.

Comment: I tried that.. it gave me the same error thats why i asked again

Comment: Ok, then add the method where your error shows up to the question above and indicate which lines are "wrong"

Comment: you forgot the brackets :) change it from `getAmount` to `getAmount()`. Because `getAmount` is not a variable of `StudentLoan` but a method call.

Comment: It's ok, but to avoid such little mistakes you could use auto-complete (in Eclipse hit Ctrl+Space) to see suggestions of what you might try to do.

Comment: Well, the code only removes 1 string of data from the array list.. not multiple.. i edited the code as it is now

Comment: @user3053139 it should work as intended with this code. Are you sure there are multiple loans with amount 0?

Comment: By the way you can remove `index = 0` and `index++` from `removeClearedLoans` and in your loop in the method `printOutstandingLoans` you should move `int index = 0` BEFORE the `for`loop! Otherwise `index` will always be 0.

Comment: Yes, i add multiple loans.. but it removes only 1... and yeah, i corrected the the index in the printOutstandingLoans.. i noticed that issue :)

Comment: I found the problem.. calling `.remove` while iterating over a list is a bad thing because it can lead to undefined behaviour. See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! where is the edit tho? i dont see any edits in your code

Comment: Just got done, sorry :D should've edited before commenting :)

Comment: Ah :) java.util :) didnt think about looking there :) i am still new with all the classes in the packages, but tank you again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have a getter for the variable Amount in the StudentLoan objects, ie, getAmount().  If not, you should create one.

The print method would change to:

```
public void printLoanDitails()
{
    System.out.println("Loan Summery: ");
    int index=0;  //This should be outside the loop, or it will be set to 0 each time
    for(StudentLoan loans : loan) {

        if(loans.getAmount() > 0)
        {
            System.out.print(index + " : ");
            loans.printDetails();
            index++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

You should probably add this logic to the PayOff method as well.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly sure what you are doing with your print statement without seeing your studnetLoan class

You have:

```
for(StudentLoan loans : loan) {
        int index=0;
        System.out.print(index + " : ");
        loans.printDetails();
        index++;
    }
```

I Would do something more like this:

```
for(StudentLoan loan : loanList) {         
        if(loan.getAmount() > 0) 
           loan.printDetails();

    }
```

Note that I have named the list of loans "loanList" or it could be "loans" but it makes no sense to call it "loan"